# Conditional Formatting Formula for Comparison

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have this spreadsheet

[image]
I have been trying to come up with a conditional formatting formula that will allow me to deconflict meeting times. If there are two meetings on Tue at 10 (as shown), I'd like the column to turn red. I can't find a way to do this without having hundreds of statements in the formula. There's got to be a simpler way I just don't know about. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use COUNTIFS with the Day and Time as criteria and check if the result is greater than 1.

Comment: I tried ```=COUNTIFS(O5,O$5:O$15)```.  The problem is I have to apply the rule only to column O. I can't have a separate rule for each column. Is there a way to apply one rule to the whole grid that will have the same effect?

Comment: Your `COUNTIFS` should have two criteria, and the references should all be absolute, i.e. preceded by a `$`.

Comment: doesn't the comparison to the column do both day and time? what's the other criteria? I wish I could just script this. lol.

Comment: I can't tell what column `O` is in your screenshot, but my commentary is based off of the `Tue` and `10` criteria under the columns `IPR Day` and `IPR Time`.

Comment: Oh ok. Screenshot updated. Column O is in the date grid, on Tue at 10.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS($H:$H,$H5,$I:$I,$I5,$H:$H,"<>TBD",$I:$I,"<>TBD")>1` maybe

Comment: Or `=COUNTIFS(O$5:O$15,O5,O$5:O$15,"<>""")>1` maybe

Comment: The first formula makes the whole row on the two conflicted meetings red. I thought about just highlighting the cells in the date grid. But seeing this highlight the whole row, I find it easier to notice the conflict. I think that's better.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ben!

Comment: I think the conditional formatting is checking so many cells every time there's a change that the workbook is lagging.

Comment: Then change the full column references to something smaller.

Comment: When I restrict even the TBD check, it no longer changes any format.  ```=COUNTIFS($H:$H,$H5,$I:$I,$I5,$H$5:$H$15,"<>TBD",$I$5:$I$15,"<>TBD")>1```

Comment: You have to change the `$H:$H`, and `$I:$I` as well. In `COUNTIFS`, the ranges to look in must all be the same size. Currently they are not.

Comment: That's why the `>1` check... the COUNTIFS will always be at a minimum `=1`. You just need to check if greater than one.

Comment: That did it. Thanks again.